# Put image onto header

Tags: images, css, headers

I'm using the new Twenty Seventeen Theme on WordPress and I want to insert an image with a link on top of the header. How can I do this? I tried messing around with the editor but no results. Any help??

Answer (score 0):

First of all gain access to website files using FTP account, if you are not familiar with it, just google "FTP" and "FileZilla" and read some lines.

Then go to `/wp-content/themes/Twenty Seventeen/header.php` 
insert the image html where you wish it to be